# Successfully checking out svn files but no SCM status displayed in the navigator nor the source control utility area

Tags: xcode, xcode4.3

I have a Subversion repository on a local network which contains a set of files (which I added using Versions).

Using Xcode I selected Checkout or Clone Repository and the files successfully were transferred to my desktop.

However when I open the Xcode project from the checked out files there is no SCM status displayed for any of the files in Xcode's navigator, nor is there a source control entry for any of the files within the utility area.

How do I make SCM status appear?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to install "Command Line Tools" from XCode preferences -> Downloads -> Components.

Answer (score 0):

Select project root and click File->Source Control->Show Working Copy Status